# Add one to each cell before passing to formula

Tags: excel

I would like to take the geomean of a column where values may be less than 1. I would like to add one to each cell before calculating geomean, and I do not want to include hidden rows in my calculation.

So far I have been using `=POWER(AGGREGATE(6,5,O6:O22),1/AGGREGATE(2,5,O6:O22))` because this allows me to ignore hidden rows. However, this is mathematically incorrect when the value in a given cell in O6:O22 is less than 1. I want to bias the values up by 1, do the calculation, then unbias the results at the end. In effect, something like `=POWER(AGGREGATE(6,5,O6:O22 + 1),1/AGGREGATE(2,5,O6:O22 + 1)) - 1`

I know that array formulas can do things like this, but I haven't found an example that works yet. The above is not the syntactically correct, despite examples I have found suggesting otherwise.

I am deliberately trying to avoid another hidden column for calculations because I already hide columns and rows on this sheet for data presentation purposes. It would be cumbersome to constantly rehide calculation columns when unhiding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is the formula to use based on your formula(See below for shorter version).

```
=POWER(PRODUCT(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(O6:O22,ROW(O6:O22)-MIN(ROW(O6:O22)),,1)),O6:O22+1)),1/SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(O6:O22,ROW(O6:O22)-MIN(ROW(O6:O22)),,1))))-1
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT:

You can use GEOMEAN() with the IF() from above to return the same in a shorter formula:

```
=GEOMEAN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(O6:O22,ROW(O6:O22)-MIN(ROW(O6:O22)),,1)),O6:O22+1))-1
```

Still an Array Formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]